# How to create a docker image by extending a docker image which was already created

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am creating a docker image as follows
 stage('Build'){
            agent any

```
        steps{
            script {
              dockerImage = docker.build("my_docker_image", "${MY_ARGS} .")
             }
      }
```

in a Jenkins file Build stage

I want to create a new Docker image based on the image I created but with additional configurations on the build Stage to use in the test stage.

Is there a way to do it using the dockerImage ?

Comment: Why not make another dockerfile for it and build it?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I can reuse most of the stuff if I can do  it in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse images in other dockerfile also for re-usability

Let's assume we have below dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./server.py .
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

Now you build it using below

```
docker build -t production .
```

Now let's assume you want another testing image which should have telnet installed. Now instead of repeating the dockerfile you can start from the `production` image which is present locally only

```
FROM production
RUN apt update && apt install -y telnet
```

Then build the same using below

```
docker build -f Dockerfile-testing -t testing .
```

As you can see there is no duplication of Dockerfile content in this, which is what you probably want